# UnauthorizedAccessException trying to access /tmp on AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I am trying to use the /tmp folder on an AWS Lambda to download and execute the Chrome Selenium webdriver through WebDriverManager but I keep getting an UnauthorizedAccessException trying to access /tmp. I thought /tmp could be used for this sort of thing but google doesn't seem to be providing any help, here is my code:

```
    public IWebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        var tmpPath = Path.GetTempPath();

        new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(
            "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.25/chromedriver_linux64.zip",
            tmpPath,
            "chromedriver"
        );

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments(new List<string>() {
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--headless",
            "--disable-gpu",
            $"--homedir={tmpPath}"
        });
        return new ChromeDriver(tmpPath, options);
    }
```

and my exception

```
  "errorType": "AggregateException",
  "errorMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path '/tmp/' is denied.)",
  "stackTrace": [
      "at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)",
      "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ],
```

Has anyone managed to successfully use DriverManager to run a headless chrome instance on an AWS Lambda? Would appreciate some pointers.

TIA

Rich

Comment: Does the lambda function have enough memory to be able to save the ChromeDriver? May you can try by increasing the memory for the lambda..

Comment: If you want to run UI Automation, I suggest to use containers instead of Lambda functions.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have't changed the memory allocation from whatever is default, although shouldn't I expect a different exception if I ran out of memory rather than UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to the path '/tmp/' is denied.

Comment: @Dutts Hello. Did you get anywhere with this? Thanks